# Android with Intent and Custom Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I customize a `ListView` using the `ArrayAdapter`, but when I run it on the smartphone, I click the item but it's not dark, such as not being interactive.
And a problem:
 when I using `Intent` with a `TextView` on an Item in `ListView` by `ArrayAdapter`, an error with "`Error:(64, 71) error: not an enclosing class: PlaylistActivity`"

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

**`AdapterCustom.java`**

```
public class AdapterCustom extends BaseAdapter {
...

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup ) {

        final LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view=inflater.inflate(layout,null);

    TextView tvFeelOnday= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_feel);
    TextView tvFeelDate=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_feel_date);

    Feel mFeel= FeelList.get(i);

    tvFeelOnday.setText(mFeel.getmFeelOnDay().toString());
    tvFeelDate.setText(mFeel.getmFeelDate()+"");


    tvFeelOnday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Hehe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);// an error
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: `intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)` here `this` does not refer to context. You need a context as a param there instead

Comment: then i use 
public class FeelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mcontext;
    private int layout;
    private List<Feel> FeelList;    
   .....
tvFeelOnday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(mcontext, com.BKDN.Cellular.MusicActivity.class);

                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Hehe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;

but i cannot startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your activity context and use that context for create new activity.
Make one constructor for initialize context.

```
public AdapterCustom(Context context) {
          this.context = context;     
     }
```